# Finding eigenvalues of a large matrix close to a given value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

In [an address from 1997](https://www.maa.org/centrality-of-linear-algebra), Carl Cowen said:

> [I]n 1974, a graduate student friend studying civil
> engineering and working on modeling vibrations in buildings caused by
> earthquakes asked me how he could find the eigenvalues of a $200×200$
> matrix that were close to $12$. (Unfortunately, at the time, I had no
> clue—the best advice I had to offer was to find all $200$ and check
> which were closest to $12$; I know better now!)

What *is* the smart way to do this?

Comment: Subtract 12, invert the matrix, and find the largest eigenvalues. You can find the largest ones by repeatedly squaring and normalizing - it’ll converge to a point where the columns are eigenvectors with eigenvalue the largest value (which are $1/(x-12)$ where x is the closest eigenvalue to 12)

Comment: Given context, the matrix is likely symmetric real and the eigenvalues distinct..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword here is [inverse iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration): given a guess $\mu$ for the eigenvalue (here $12$) this algorithm finds an eigenvector with eigenvalue close to $\mu$, without solving the whole system.